# Replacing elements of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix in R that looks something like

```
T F T T F 
F T F T T 
T T T F F
```

What I want to do is to change, say, the first 2 columns to all T's. So, I want the output to look like:

```
T T T T F
T T F T T
T T T F F
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I'm new to R, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: `x[,1:2] <- "T"` if your matrix called x. R is a vectorized language, you can do stuff like very easily

Comment: It's essentially a matrix of True's and False's. I think this should work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a logical matrix, use

```
x[,1:2] <- T
```

or better, a more secure (and clear)

```
x[,1:2] <- TRUE
```

why more secure? because different users can assign different values to `T`, eg

```
> T <- 0
> T == TRUE
[1] FALSE
```

but weird things are not allowed on `TRUE`:

```
> TRUE <- 0
Error in TRUE <- 0 :
```

An example of harmful error could be in function defaults definition, eg

```
my.print <- function(val = T) {
    cat(val, "\n")
}

T <- "foo"

my.print()
# foo
```